# Can I deal with Records in an easier way in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I started to tackle CakePHP and read through the documentation, but two things still seem a bit clumsy to me.

1. I know other Frameworks where I have a **certain** record which I'd like to store, but CakePHP suggests me to do it anonymously:

   ```
   $this->Foo->create(array(...));
   $this->Foo->save();
   ```

   Why can't I tell CakePHP which Record to save, just like in every other framework:

   ```
   $foo = $this->Foo->create(array(...));
   $foo->save();
   ```
2. I would like to iterate through a whole RecordSet inside of a Controller. Why do I need to iterate using

   ```
   $foos = $this->Foos->find('all');
   foreach($foos as $foo){
      $foo['Foo'] // ... here we have $foo.
   ```

   I don't understand why `find()` returns a 2-dimensional array and there are only records in the inner array. Why isn't this directly an array of records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $this->Foo is an instance of your Foo model. When you call methods on it, you are calling methods on the active record (if there is one) of that instance of the Foo model. So in terms of telling Cake which record to save, you don't need to - Cake knows to save the current active record.

Here's the code you pasted with comments, which might help.

```
// Prepare this instance of the Foo model to save a new record
$this->Foo->create(array(...));

// Save the new record that we have just prepared
$this->Foo->save();
```

And the other way...

```
// Call the create method on this instance of the Foo model, and return what?
// Return another instance of the Foo model?
// Why not just continue using the instance we already have, ie, $this->Foo
$foo = $this->Foo->create(array(...));

// Call the save method on the duplicate instance of the Foo model that was
// returned from the create method?
$foo->save(); 

// Why did 'create' need to return a duplicate instance of the model to do a save???
// Why not call the save on the same instance of the Foo model that we used to call the create?
```

Point 2. This is basically for consistency. Often, you'll be returning data from multiple tables, linked to one another. Lets say tables Foo and Bar have a 1 to 1 relationship, and you're getting Foo records, along with their associated Bar records.The array returned will need Foo and Bar keys, eg: inside of your foreach loop, $foo might contain:

$foo['Foo']['column1'], $foo['Foo']['column2'], $foo['Bar']['column1'], $foo['Bar']['column2']

To be consistent, when you only fetch from one table, it still returns in the form $foo['Foo']['column1'], just like it would if you fetched joined data from multiple tables.

EDIT: In response to your comment, say you have the code:

```
$foos = $this->Foos->find('all');
```

Say you wanted to call some model method on each row of your returned array, there are a few ways you could do it. One way is something like:

```
// This is code for the controller
$this->Car->find('all');
foreach($cars as $car){
    $this->Car->driveTwoMiles($car); // the driveTwoMiles would be in your model class

}
```

So in your model, you'd have a method:

```
// This would be a method in your model class
function driveTwoMiles($car){
    $this->id = $car['Car']['id']; // set the active record
    // we are now inside the model, so $this->id is the same as calling $this->Car->id from the controller

    // Do whatever you want here. You have an active record, and your $car variable, holding data
    $this->Post->saveField('distance_driven', $car['Car']['distance_driven']+2);
}
```

Also, for cases where you just want to update one record, not many, you can just do a "read" rather than a "find('all')" - more info in the links below.

I would highly recommend reading all the way through these pages in the cake cook book:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html - Retrieving Data

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html - Saving data

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html - Deleting data

All contain really important foundational info on how to work with Cake Models. Spend the time to really understand it now, and you'll save yourself countless headaches and code re-factors in future!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Point 2: But these are still only raw data arrays without any objects in it. That way I can't call any of the model's methods like: `$car->driveTwoMiles()` or `$car->getDrivers()`. Can't I do this in CakePHP?

Comment: I've just re-edited my edit... sorry if you were reading this while I was editing - but now it should make more sense!